Simple example of C++ calling Python using Pybind11 and CMake
I have a simple C++ main.cpp file with two vectors I'd like to pass to a Python function:
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec1;
    std::vector<double> vec2;
}

python.py:
def python_function(list_1, list_2):
    # Code

I've git-cloned Pybind11 and make-installed it. Now I'd like to write a simple CMake script to compile the above.
I found this page:
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html
which contains some details on CMake with Pybind but I don't understand their example:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.18)
project(example LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)

However, I don't want the C++ executable to be a Pybind module. I'd like my Python file/functions to be callable from C++.
Would someone please help me finish the CMake to compile this small project? I'm also unsure how I inform Pybind where my python file is located.

You need to embed s Python interpreter in your program. Pybind11 has a way of doing that, but if you don't also need modules written in C++ then it's probably a better idea to use plain C Python API instead.

https://github.com/ResearchDaniel/python3-embedded-example

As it was mentioned in comments you need to embed python interpreter into your C++ project. pybind11 documentation about it is here
There you can find example of CMake script. Namely:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5...3.27)
project(example)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)  # or `add_subdirectory(pybind11)`

add_executable(example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE pybind11::embed)

In order to execute python code in C++ pybind11 provides several functions:
py::exec, py::eval and py::eval_file. If you want to execute python code from file, use the last one, it accepts as an input argument path to the file
Also here are some examples of py::eval_file usage.
